# Using vlookup to find date over 30 days

Tags: excel, formula

I am using this formula in B1

```
=today() -30
```

I use this to show a the day 30 days ago.

Colum C2 is a list of account numbers and D3 is the dates, I am trying to list all account number that have dates over 30 days on them

I am trying to use the following formula:

```
=vlookup(C:C,C2:D22,'<=B1',TRUE)
```

This doesnt work, but cant get my head around why.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: That isn't how VLookup works...`=VLOOKUP (lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup])`... there are a few ways to accomplish what you are looking for.  I'd do a filter or a conditional formatting.

Comment: I struggle with conditional formatting, and vlookup - Very new to me so winging it to be honest. Trial and error but not getting far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not going to accomplish this with a simple [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65). Use the [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) to pass the matching row numbers to an [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a).

Get the first matching record with,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C:C, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$22)/((D$1:D$22<=TODAY()-30)*(D$1:D$22>0)), ROW(1:1))), "")
```

Fill down for the remaining matches.

[image]

Comment: This worked perfetly, Im trying to understand the formula and its way over my head I need to find a way to teach myself in laymans terms - thank you so much

Comment: The real defining factor here is AGGREGATE's ability to discard errors with the **6** parameter. Any row number that does not match the two conditions (less than 30 days previous but greater than zero) is divided by zero and that results in an error. By discarding the `#DIV/0!` errors, you are left with a set of matching row numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method is to use a Filter.  Highlight your data table and click on `Filter` under `Sort & Filter` in the `Editing` section of the ribbon.

Then, click on the down arrow on your list of dates header (filter selection arrow), then `Date Filters`, then `Before`.

Here is the menu that pops up:

[image]